# rbenv: no such command `shell' - Configure RBENV per app/directory on 16.04 sudo environment

Tags: ruby, rbenv

Running (x)ubuntu 16.04 with sudo user ...

installed rbenv with local user + sudo plugin

```
    cd ~
    git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git .rbenv
    echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
    echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc


    git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
    echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc

    # sudo plugin
    git clone git://github.com/dcarley/rbenv-sudo.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-sudo

rbenv install 2.4.1
rbenv global 2.4.1
ruby -v
```

**The `shell` command is not working with this setup, what am i missing?**

Is there a different way than the `shell` command to set RBENV (rubyversion) for a github project for example?

EDIT1: **it appears when RBENV shell is called manually through terminal it works, just not in a #!/bin/bash script**

Comment: Did you run `source ~/.bashrc`?

Comment: of course. Maybe some profile file edit required? scambled google already but could find a solution.

Comment: see EDIT1 , end of text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your edit, it sounds like the problem stems from not running the script from your interactive shell. [Non-interactive shells](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) that aren't invoked with the `--login` options don't source .bashrc or any other files. You can source .bashrc manually at the start of your shell script:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

You could also just initialize rbenv and not any of your other configurations by adding this line to your shell script:

```
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```